# reference to java.lang.annotation.Annotation from Class?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I'm having a tough time trying to figure out how to get a reference to a *java.lang.annotation.Annotation* from its actual implementing class.

The annotation itself looks like this (from a framework):

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RequiresPermissions {
    ...snip...
}
```

In my using code, I would like to do something like this:

```
Annotation requiresPermissionAnnotation = RequiresPermissions.class;
```

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what or how to cast this, or what typing I can employ to get it.

As a work around, I could have a simple class that has a method with this annotation (and others), and use reflection methods on the Class to get the *java.lang.annotation.Annotation*, but that just seems odd..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of the annotation only exists for an annotated type/method. This is how you can get it

```
Annotation requiresPermissionAnnotation = SomeAnnotatedClass.class.getAnnotation(RequiresPermissions.class);
```

You can cast to `RequiresPermissions` to access any attributes.

```
RequiresPermissions requiresPermissions = (RequiresPermissions) requiresPermissionAnnotation;
```

or get it directly

```
RequiresPermissions requiresPermissions = SomeAnnotatedClass.class.getAnnotation(RequiresPermissions.class);
```

For a method

```
Annotation requiresPermissionAnnotation = someMethodInstance.getAnnotation(RequiresPermissions.class);
```

Comment: You can just do `RequiresPermissions r = someAnnotatedClass.getAnnotation(RequiresPermissions.class)`. Simpler, and no cast necessary.

Comment: @Jesper Absolutely. Just sticking to their snippet.

Comment: Thanks - the comment "An instance of the annotation only exists for an annotated type/method" is what I needed to read; seems like I will have to have a dummy class whose purpose is only "host" these annotations so I can get a reference

Answer (score 1):

Say, that you have some class `MyClass`, which is annotated with the `RequiresPermissions` annotation:

```
@RequiresPermissions("something")
public class MyClass {
    // ...
}
```

If you want to see the values of the annotation for `MyClass` in your program, you can do this:

```
RequiresPermissions anno = MyClass.class.getAnnotation(RequiresPermissions.class);

System.out.println(anno.value());
```

(I don't know what attributes your `RequiresPermissions` annotation has; you can call them on the `anno` object to get the values).

Answer (score 1):

The property `.class` returns a `Class` object, which you'll have to assign to any super type of `Class`. It's not an instance of the annotation, so trying to assign it to an `Annotation` won't work. To keep a reference to the type of an annotation, you have a few options:

```
// use the actual class
Class<MyAnnotation> annotationClass1 = MyAnnotation.class;

// use a bounded wildcard
Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass2 = (Class<? extends Annotation>) MyAnnotation.class;

// use an unbound wildcard, not recommended
Class<?> annotationClass3 = MyAnnotation.class;
```